# Recyclerview different item elevation on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to make a recycler view with different item elevation onScroll

[[image: like this image:[1]]

[Like this video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zB-YyJMe4pss_VQ_LW5-A92QWqqXMnWF)

Comment: Is the picture what you desire or what is currently happening - show the layout file as well  or code if it is programmatic.  Looks like `android:gravity="center_vertical"` but just guessing since you need to post your layout.

Comment: i want to change the recyclerview childs elevation like this video   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zB-YyJMe4pss_VQ_LW5-A92QWqqXMnWF

Comment: I think that you want to change the animation, small in the laterals and big the selected.  To this, you need to use in your viewholder the setOnFocusChangeListener.  When the view has focus then scale the picture to do big, and when the picture lost the focus, then scale the picture to recover the default size.

Answer (score 0):

if you're not already using `ViewPager2` you should try to check what it does, you can apply transformations to pages (items). As you haven't provided any code, i can only reply in a general context.
You can achieve the result you want with the following code:

```
ViewPager2.PageTransformer { page, position ->
page.apply {
        translationY = Math.abs(position) * 500f
        scaleX = 1f
        scaleY = 1f
    }
}
```

then

```
viewPager2.setPageTransformer(CompositePageTransformer().also {
    it.addTransformer(marginPageTransformer)
    it.addTransformer(translationPageTransformer())
})
```

check [this](https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419) link for more explanation